# Python xlrd: test if string is in row

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to iterate through a workbook until I find a particular string.

```
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(myfile)
for s in wb.sheets()
    for r in range(0,s.nrows):
        print(r)
        if 'flag' in s.row(r):
            print('Do stuff')
```

The value of r is printed, but stuff is never done. I have also tried:

```
if 'flag' in s.cell_value(r,0):
```

which is clearly limited to looking in the first column, and it still doesn't work when the value is in the first column.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(myfile)
for s in wb.sheets()
for r in range(0,s.nrows):
    print(r)
    if 'flag' in [str(x) for x in s.row(r)]:
        print('Do stuff')
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh, I needed:

```
if 'flag' in s.row_values(r):
```

Hope this helps someone else.